# If I switch from 32-bit to 64-bit MS Office 365, will my settings be ported?

Tags: 64-bit, office365, 32-bit

I have installed the 32-bit version of Office 365, but realize I should probably be using the 64-bit. I have made some customized in the 32-bit version: themes, custom toolbars, etc.

This [page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/choose-between-the-64-bit-or-32-bit-version-of-office-2dee7807-8f95-4d0c-b5fe-6c6f49b8d261) recommends that I uninstall the 32bit version, then install the 64 bit version.

If I uninstall the 32-bit version and install the 64-bit version instead, will my customization and settings be ported?

(I'm on Windows 10 Pro, using Microsoft 365 Apps for enterprise.)

Answer (score 2):

Most things will be kept - possibly not all - but most things.

I have converted from Office 32-bit to Office 64-bit on two machines. All email, All documents, printers, One Note, and most other things retained.

Nothing major (if anything) not kept.

So (a) I am very happy with Office 64-bit (nearly 2 years now) and (b) I think you should ensure obvious backups and then move forward to Office 64-bit.

New installs / new machines are now Office 64-bit so when you need to do one or the other, 64-bit will be installed.

Answer (score 1):

In the **word-settings-customize ribbon**, you can export all your customizations and save the customization files to the installation file for 64-bit Office.
[image]